# How normal pin (GPIO PIN) works as RX/TX in softwareSerial library in arduino?

Tags: arduino, serial-communication, software-serial

I found that pin 10 and pin 11  often used in the software-serial library in Arduino or having priority to it?

is there any Memory peripheral bus is attached to it?

Comment: Not sure what you're actually asking here....

Comment: most of time pin 10 is used as RX and 11 as Tx ,if softwareserial library is being used? why not other pin....is any buffer at that pin.i just read that 64K buffer is there or any other reason?

Answer (score 0):

I think the point is that the [SoftwareSerial](http://arduino.cc/en/pmwiki.php?n=Reference/SoftwareSerial) library requires change interrupts. Since Arduino Mega, Mega 2560, Leonardo as well as Micro supports change interrupts on the pins 10,11, it is maybe a good decision to write examples based on these pins and avoid further problems of pin capabilities with different Arduino boards...